# How to set permisions for var/cache folder?

Tags: magento2.3, file-permissions, ubuntu

I can't able to remove var/cache folder. I'm using local server and accessed through ssh. How can I remove the var/cache folder by setting permission?

I have run `chmod 755 -R var/*` and getting the below error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--6': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--6/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_WEBSITES_1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--6/mage---4c4_CORE_CACHE_INVALIDATE': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--5': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--5/mage---4c4_GLOBAL__DICONFIG': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--5/mage---4c4_EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_CONFIG': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--7': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--7/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_STORES_1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--7/mage---4c4_INTERCEPTION': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--8': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--8/mage---4c4_INITIAL_CONFIG': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--8/mage---4c4_GLOBAL__EVENT_CONFIG_CACHE': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--0': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--0/mage---4c4_CRON_GROUPS_CONFIG_CACHE': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--3': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--3/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_WEBSITES_ADMIN': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--a': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--a/mage---4c4_GLOBAL_PRIMARY_PLUGIN_LIST': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--1/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_STORES_ADMIN': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--9': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--9/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_WEBSITES_0': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--e': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--e/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_STORES_0': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--4': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--4/mage---4c4_DICONFIGF43A730BCC60DA5CA955D2AF4C707B0D': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--d': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--d/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_STORES_DEFAULT': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--f': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--f/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_SCOPES': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--c': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--c/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_WEBSITES_BASE': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--b': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--b/mage---4c4_SYSTEM_DEFAULT': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/cache/mage--b/mage---4c4_SYSTEM': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/.htaccess': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/cache': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/cache/files': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/cache/repo': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/cache/repo/https---repo.magento.com': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/composer_home/cache/.htaccess': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/debug': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/debug/db.log': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/log': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/log/system.log': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of 'var/resource_config.json': Operation not permitted
```

1. OS: Ubuntu/Linux
2. Magento Version: 2.3.2

Comment: try with sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/

Answer (score 3):

Run this command:

```
chmod -R 777 var/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run below command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
sudo rm -rf var/cache
```

Comment: I have run this command and got "xyz is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: try run command with root user or the user which have permissions

Comment: Also share your error screenshot

Comment: this command not for change permission.

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Run this command

```
chown -f owner:group var/
```